# How to completely drop sshexec output in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a command which prints a lot of useless data into STDOUT. I need to call it via sshexec from another box. I need all of the command's output to be completely dropped.
How can I achieve that?

I have the following code in my build.gradle to call the command:

```
sshexec {
    config(StrictHostKeyChecking: 'no')
    session(remotes.remote1) {
        execute("cd somewhere && toomuchverbosescript.sh")
    }
}
```

Comment: what about `... > /dev/null` ?

Comment: Henry, yep, that's an option. So obivious I even didn't think about.
I even did add 2>&1 to make it more quiet.